# change controlname dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a some problem

i.e i have a 60 text box controls in asp page i want to text box text to empty so , i am using like below

```
var st = document.getElementById("<%=hiddenrate.ClientID%>").value;//Total Control names

var controlnames = st.split(','); //split with comma 

var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= controlnames.length; i++)
{
    var gh = '' + '.SetText(' + "'Empty text'" + '' + ');';

    ft[i] + gh;

    //example rate1.SetText('');

    rate2.SetText('');
    '
    '
    rate60..SetText('');
}
```

but in javascript is that control name and property

How to set text as empty in total controls dynamically?

Thanking You,

Rajesh

Comment: Is hiddenrate.value a comma-separated list of the control ids?

Comment: hi matthew crumley,

yes, ids are separated by comma. i using aspx DevExpress control.
Can u give any solutions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to clear the values of all text inputs use this code:

```
// get all <input> elements
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // check input type
    if (inputs[i].type === 'text') {
        inputs[i].text = '';
    }
}
```

You could easily modify that code to handle textareas as well or add some more filtering to the elements.

If you consider using JS framework you can make this code much shorter. For example if you use jQuery then here's the code for you:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').text('');
});
```

Comment: thanks for u r answer but it is not work for ASPX control properties
and also  document.getElementsByTagName('input'); not supported by aspx 
 can u give code for aspx controls ?

Comment: This is JS (client side language) which has nothing to do with ASP (which is server side)

Comment: hi Ray Yell i tried your code but it is throwing an error 

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

i am using ASPX (DevExpress Controls) it is not support what u mentioned code can u give any another way to do this?
 thanking you

Comment: I added an alternative solution if you are willing to use jQuery framework in your app. In most cases using a framework (not necessarily this one, but it's quite popular) is a very good idea. All you need to do is include `jquery.js` to your page and start using it.

Comment: i got the solution
Thanking you u r help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another sample to clear value all textboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function pp(){
          for(p in form1.childNodes) {
              if(form1.childNodes(p).type=="text")
                  form1.childNodes(p).value="";
          }
    }
</script>

<body>
  <form name="form1">
      <input type="text" name="a1"/>
      <input type="text" name="a2"/>
      <input type="text" name="a3"/>
      <input type="button" name="a11"/>
      <input type="submit" name="a12"/>
      <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="pp()" name="a13"/>

   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply calling [document.forms["form1"].reset()](http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Javascript_Reset_Form.shtml) in Javascript? It will clear the values of all the controls in the form.

Comment: sorry matthew Lock i want only some text boxes in aspx
can you give any code for dynamically change control names.
example

control1.Settext('');
control2.Settext('');
"
"
control50.Settext('');
control'Dynamicnubmers' .settext('');

thanks matthew

Answer (score 0):

Thanking u all i got the solution like below method
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= ft.length; i++) {

```
               x = new Object();
               x = ft[i];
               propertyName = ".SetText";
               propertyValue = " ";
               if(x !="undefined")
               eval(''+x+'' + propertyName + "('" + propertyValue + "');");
               or

              eval(x).SetText('');
            }
```

thnks to all.